# Why `ORDER BY` can use nonexist column at its execution time?

Tags: sql

Say I have a movies table and an actors table with movie_id foreign key

```
SELECT movies.id, movies.title
JOIN actors
ON movies.id = actors.movie_id
GROUP BY movies.id
ORDER BY COUNT(movies.id) DESC
```

This will correctly give me the movies ordered by actor counts.

But I thought the first 4 lines, should generate a table like

```
id title 
2. Titanic
3. Fight club
1. Casablanca
```

Each movie id should only appear once, how could ORDER BY order by the count of it? Unless SQL is doing some underneath magic to secretly calculate `COUNT(movies.id)` when executing the first 4 lines

Comment: You mean as the [order of execution of SQL](https://www.designcise.com/web/tutorial/what-is-the-order-of-execution-of-an-sql-query) that SQL will do step by step: JOIN, then GROUP BY, then SELECT, then how can it ORDER BY without knowing the COUNT(\*)? 
IMO it would `parse` the query first, then it will know that it should calculate COUNT(\*) in the GROUP BY/SELECT step, so that in ORDER BY step it will have information to sort. You know, SQL is not an unknown magical entity, it is just a program written by, hmm, some nerds.

Answer (score 2):

Interesting question.  `ORDER BY` can use any expression that *could* be in the `SELECT`.  Internally, SQL does the calculation and so it can be used.

This not only applies to functions such as `COUNT(*)`, but also functions with arguments.  Or any expression of them.  For instance, this would be allowed:

```
ORDER BY LENGTH(movies.title) DESC
```

to get the longest movie names first -- well assuming your database has a `LENGTH()` function.